# Symfony2 tests : filter with html:contains return one value

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, tdd

I want to test my Symfony2 application with PHPUnit when a user submits a form without any data.

My validations are activared, so error messages are displayed correctly in a navigator. For example in the entity :

```
class Foo
{

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255)
     */
   private $city;

}
```

And the type of this entity :

```
class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('city', 'text');
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I submit the form without any data, the response contains 2 messages "This value should not be blank".

So in my tests I want to retrieve this 2 messages, but the filter function just returns 1 :

```
public function testShouldNotSaveANewFooWhenDataIsEmpty()
{
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/foo/new');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Add')->form(array(
        'foo[name]'  => '',
        'foo[city]'  => ''
    ));

    $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);
    echo $crawler->filter('html:contains("This value should not be blank")')->count(); // Should display 2, not 1
}
```

Have you got any idea please ?

Comment: Maybe because `foo[name]` and `bureau[city]` don't fill the two fields?

Comment: Oops, error in my copy/paste. Fixed in my question, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selector `html:contains("This value should not be blank")` that you use means *get every `<html>` tag containing the `"This value should not be blank"` string*. Even if this string is present twice, there is only one `<html>` tag per page, so you will never count 2 filtered items.

The solution is to use a more specific rule:

```
$crawler->filter('div:contains("This value should not be blank")')
```

Use the name of the tag which contains your error messages. By default it's `<div>` but you may have changed this in your Twig template.